# MySQL JOINS always return same number of results even if the WHERE does not match

Tags: mysql, join

Sorry for the confusing title but is kind of difficult to explain.

I have three tables in MySQL: `zones(id, name)`, `sellers(id, name)`, `geopricings(id, zone [FK references zones.id], seller [FK references sellers.id], value)`

Every seller has a different price (`geopricings.value`) based on the zone.

In the `geopricings` table I should have 9 rows for each seller ( there are 9 zones in total ) with the corresponding value, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi1zc.jpg), so if there are 10 sellers I would have a total of 90 rows.

Every time I select a seller from a dropdown, I want to create a form with 9 price inputs that are populated if the seller prices are already inserted, or empty if the seller prices have yet to be inserted.

This query returns 9 rows if the seller prices are already inserted, but it returns an empty set if the seller is not ( the `WHERE` clause fails ).

```
$getRows = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT zones.*, geopricings.value 
    FROM zones LEFT JOIN geopricings ON zones.id = geopricings.zone 
    WHERE geopricings.seller = :seller
");

$getRows->execute(array( 'seller' => $_POST['seller'] ));

$rows = $getRows->fetchAll();
```

Then I will generate the form

```
<div id="geoZones" class="sizeTableQta zoneTable w100 cf">

    <?php foreach($rows as $zone): ?>
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="zone[]" class="input w50 fl" value="<?= $zone->id ?>">
            <span><?= $zone->name ?></span>
            <input type="text" name="value[]" class="input w50 fl" value="<?= $zone->value ?>">
        </p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

So if the seller is not inserted the form is empty, but instead I want to generate the form with empty inputs so I can insert a new seller in the geopricings table.

I know that the problem is with the query, so I need to modify it so it ALWAYS returns 9 rows no matter if the `seller.id` is already in the `geopricings` table or not.

It sounds confusing but I will try to explain further if it is difficult to understand.

I hope you can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: To limit to 9 rows use `limit 9` at the end of the query.  But that only limits higher numbers down to 9.  It won't magically create 9 rows for you when the query is empty.

Comment: your query would only return anything if a seller exists. you'd need to explicitly allow the case where a seller DOESN'T exist, e.g. `left join .... where seller=:seller or seller is null`. in other words, you want more of an outer join, not the inner join you're doing now.

Comment: or check in PHP if rows is null, and then do a for loop to 9 to create your HTML for that case, and if its not null, do your foreach on rows